# chrome.identity in development

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm confused by how I can develop a Chrome App with `chrome.identity`.

The [instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) say that I need to add the key to my `manifest.json`, and that I need to put the extension id in the Google API Console.

I have a published version of the app, and I am currently developing a local copy, so I am loading it unpacked from my local file system.

1. Can I put the key from the published app in the dev `manifest.json`?
2. Does the extension id in the Google API Console need to be of the published app, or my local one?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you should do that to debug chrome.identity without pain.
2. If you place public key of your published app inside manifest.json, your app will have the same ID as the app in Chrome Web Store.

Comment: One last thing to add: how to get the public key for a published extension. In the Developer Dashboard main view, click on "more info" link in the item listing.